# Disable symbols and non-letters in input field

Tags: javascript, forms, input, field

I would like to disable all symbols entry into an input field  that are not associated with following: letters or numbers or spaces or ampersand symbol or full stop.

E.g.
ALLOWED: A-Z, a-z, 0-9, &, ., and space is allowed.

NOT ALLOWED: Every other character e.g. ! @ # $ % ^ * ( ) - + = [ ] ; : ' " < > , / ? | = ` ~ etc.

```
<input id="ItemName" type="text" />
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) so far?

Comment: is HTML5 OK? If so you can use a `pattern` attribute and give a simple regex. Something like `pattern="[A-Za-z0-9& .]*"`

Answer (score 1):

You can register a keypress event handler and return false if you don't "like" the new input :

```
$('#ItemName').keypress(function (e) {
    var txt = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if (!txt.match(/[A-Za-z0-9&. ]/)) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cgx1yqyf/

Note that this solution requires JQuery

Comment: That's only a partial solution. `keypress` doesn't fire if I paste or drag text into the textbox.

Comment: Won't that give an `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`?

Comment: @nnnnnn this specific solution requires the JQuery library, note that as dman2306 stated, this solution  doesn't cover paste scenarios

Comment: (Yes, I know it needs jQuery, that was my point. OP didn't mention jQuery, and your answer didn't mention it either, it just went ahead and used it.)

Comment: Hi guys, happy to use jQuery/Javascript. Your example works great but I am unable to do blank spaces? Can I have a full solution? Thanks :)

Comment: @kimtran add a space somewhere inside the []. Again though you can still paste in any character you want as it only detects key presses.

Comment: You just need o update the "regex" inside the condition

Answer (score 0):

The right way is using an "input" event.
`document.addEventListener('input', script);`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Answer (score 0):

```
Question is old, but it's never too late to answer

$(document).ready(function() {
  //prevent paste
  var usern_paste = document.getElementById('yourid');
  usern_paste.onpaste = e => e.preventDefault();

  //prevent copy
  var usern_drop = document.getElementById('yourid');
  usern_drop.ondrop = e => e.preventDefault();

$('#yourid').keypress(function (e) {
  var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]");
  var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
  if (regex.test(str)) {
      return true;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes, I know. This question is old. But I'd just give it a try (without jQuery)

**HTML**

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Try to put a non-alphabetical character here! (you can put a number and a space too)" id="nochars" />
```

**JS**

```js
const input = document.getElementById("nochars"); // gets the element (the input) by it's id
input.addEventListener("input", (event) =>  {
  const char = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)); // changes the keycode from a int to a string
  if (!(/[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.$]/.test(char))) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the default (which is adding the character to the value)
  }
});
```

Also, check on what [`EventTarget.addEventListener` does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). (`\s` is a whitespace - a space)